# Spring Security sometimes behaving weird

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using spring security for implementing the login functionality of my application. Most of the times spring security is working fine as expected. But occasionally it is going mad. At that time some login page without any of my design is opening with a username and password textbox. When I login from that not fully formed login page, some random png or js file from my homepage is getting opened. Then i will remove the corresponding js or png part from my the url and will press enter. At that time my fully formed login page gets opened and the application will work smoothly as expected. I dont know whats going on with my spring security part. Someone please help. Below is my configuration of spring security.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/loadISearch" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />  -->  

    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/dashboard1" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" /> 

    </http>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the following is what is happening:

- Your log in page is using CSS and images for styling
- Spring Security is denying access to your CSS / image files because you have not granted access to them. For this reason, the log in page looks different than what you expect and is not recognizable
- Sometimes the log in page looks normal because the CSS / images are cached by the browser.  Since the browser has cached the CSS / images it is not asking the container for the resource and Spring Security cannot protect it so the log in page renders as you expect.
- Spring Security's default policy is to save the last request that you made prior to authenticating and send the user there. Since your log in page is making additional requests to protected resources (i.e. CSS, images, etc) then after authenticating you will be sent to those pages. The result is likely non-deterministic since the requests are asynchronous.

To solve the issue make sure you grant access to all the resources your log in page uses. For example, if you place all CSS, JS, and images in a folder named /resources/ you could modify your configuration as follows:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <form-login login-page="/" 
                default-target-url="/dashboard1" 
                authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" /> 

</http>
```